# Computer will no longer boot into Windows, shows black screen instead

Tags: windows-7, boot

My PC was working fine last night. When I turned it on this morning, I couldn't get into Windows. All I saw was a black screen with some artifacts at the top.

### What I tried

- getting into safe mode, but all I saw was a black screen and a blinking cursor.
- getting into boot selection screen, saw the same thing
- I got into my BIOS, saw my 2 HDs listing there.

### What I noticed

- my HDs are kinda warm.
- there is a weird high pitch noice. not sure if it was there before.

Comment: try uplug any usbs-printers,etc, if you have any

Comment: hmm after waiting like 15 mins on that black screen. it restarted itself and loaded into windows. strange. now its working fine.

Comment: As noted by @Funky  Dude, USB devcies can cause this.  LONG boot time.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a windows repair disk, just insert that and restart your pc. Before that make sure you set BIO to boot from CD/DVD-Drive first.

You should see options for repairing your pc through the windows repair disk. It just takes few minutes. I faced the similar problem and solved it in this way.